# Pyrocms custom image field does not display uploaded image

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm rather new to PyroCMS and I have run into a problem on a project I'm working on. I have a custom image field for my blog posts which I'm trying to use for my featured image. In the admin section I create posts and upload images successfully, but after saving the post my image does not display anymore both on the front and back end.

By inspecting element on the front end (with Google Chrome) I can see the URL for the image to be displayed, but opening that URL in a new tab just outputs a lot of gibberish code. Any ideas?

This has me confused because I tried out the same setup locally on my computer using XAMPP and everything works perfectly. Contacting my web host for technical assistance resulted to me being advised to employ the services of an experienced PyroCMS developer.

Thanks.

Comment: You can view the website (under construction) here: http://newera.com.ng

Comment: if you open the url directly and get gibberish, then the raw binary data of the image isn't being sent out with the appropriate mime-type. e.g. it's going out as `text/plain` instead of `image/jpeg`. and/or it's got php warnings/errors or other non-image output somewhere causing the entire image to be treated as corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MarcB so what's the remedy?